# Having trouble getting value from Intent in Android

Tags: java, android, android-intent

Working on a project and ran into an issue with getting values from intent. I've looked at the android documentation and read the StackOverflow post, and it seems I'm doing it correctly, but still getting an error.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, DetailedTerm.class);
        // pass data to the detail view
        Term term = Objects.requireNonNull(termViewModel.allTerms.getValue()).get(position);
        intent.putExtra("id", term.getId());
        intent.putExtra("title", term.getTitle());
        intent.putExtra("start", term.getStartDate());
        intent.putExtra("end", term.getEndDate());

        Log.d("TAG", "Term values -----------------------------------\n"
                + term.getId() + " " 
                + term.getTitle() + " " 
                + term.getStartDate() + " " 
                + term.getEndDate());

        startActivity(intent);
```

Log confirms I am getting the values here ^^

Here is the receiving activity, I've tried it using getStringExtra() for all the intents and specifying the type of intent. The first gives me a null pointer, the second throws a type cast error.

```
// get values from term card and set text
        id.setText(getIntent().getStringExtra("id"));
        title.setText(getIntent().getStringExtra("title"));
        start.setText(getIntent().getStringExtra("start"));
        end.setText(getIntent().getStringExtra("end"));
```

```
        Log.d("TAG", "Term values in Detail Term\n"
                + getIntent().getIntExtra("id") + " "
                + getIntent().getStringExtra("title") + " "
                + getIntent().getFloatExtra("start") + " "
                + getIntent().getFloatExtra("end"));
```

Comment: You're logging `term` and not `intent` and "an error" is not an error description either. And on the one side you use `putExtra` and on the other side `getStringExtra`, then even `getFloatExtra`, which doesn't provide much sense. Maybe read the documentation, on how to `getStringExtra` have having `putStringExtra`? https://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-filters

Comment: That is correct I was logging the term to make sure I was getting values, logging the intent prior to sending data would produce the same results. However I went ahead and changed it to log the intent and it produces the same result. The putExtra is an overloaded method accepting multiple data types along with a string key. As for the other side that's what I'm struggling with;

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve my problem, so rather than deleting this question, I am going to post lessons learned.

There were several things going wrong for me.

1. `putExtra()` allows you to pass almost any value type along with a String key-value pair, but on the other side you have to specify the type your pulling out.

For instance.

`title.setText(getIntent().getStringExtra("title"));`

Here I have to specify I am pulling a string with the key name in quotes.

`id = getIntent().getIntExtra("id", 0);`

Here I have to specify `getIntExtra` that I am pulling an Integer, with the key name in quotes.

2. This brings to my next problem, when passing numeric values, you must pull them out with a key name but ALSO a default value. See above next to id there is 0.
3. Lastly when storing a `Date` in a Room database you need a type converter which handles conversion from `Date` type to `Long` type. That I knew, what i didn't know its this is applied atomatlic only when inserting to and from the database not everywhere else so i have to Explistliy cast the value to and from when sending along with an Intent, Like so.

`intent.putExtra("start", DateConverter.ToTimestamp(term.getStartDate()));`

and then pulling out the date

`startDate = DateConverter.fromTimestamp(getIntent().getLongExtra("start", 0));`